# Why is LaTeX telling me I have an error to do with @Arabic and c@page?

Tags: errors, page-numbering

I don't understand why LaTeX is giving me this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@Arabic 
                    \c@page 
l.1 ...berline {1}Introduction}{\@Arabic \c@page }
```

Comment: it would be great to see a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: You probably have used `\pagenumbering{Arabic}` instead of the correct `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

Comment: Not just great, as cmhughes says, but _necessary_ if we are to help you!

Comment: It was a problem with the `\tableofcontents` command. Fixed now, thanks.